# Is there any kind of face group?

Tags: materials, faces, vertex-groups

So, I'm familiar with vertex groups for saving vertex selections / groups. But, is there any way of grouping faces? Vertex groups won't suffice for the obvious reason that they often select faces I didn't originally include:

[image: Assigning vertices to the group]

[image: Selecting the vertices from the group]

I am familiar with how materials act as face groups to some extent, indicating it's very possible code-wise. But, is there a way to group faces without the need for a 'material'?

As this is for a plugin, a Blender API solution is acceptable, but it must still provide a UI for adding / removing faces from these 'face groups,' even if it means the plugin adds this interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `Vertex Groups` doesn't work.
In Blender 2.81 (or more), I use `Face Maps`.

[image]

It works like `Vertex Groups` but it is for face.
I am not sure if 2.81 is the oldest version that has this feature.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Awesomly helpful answer to start contributing!

Comment: I'll be honest, I had no idea about this :).

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ  ::  I believe it is a new feature that doesn't exist in 2.7x something. It is all credit to Blender developers - they listen to their users and greatly improve Blender usability recently.

Comment: That's incredible! I had no idea this new feature existed. Incredibly useful! Thank you cppBeginner for shedding light on this.

Comment: I forget what I wanted this for, but you're right! I'm using Blender 3.0 now, and it's in there! Thx!